# PHPSESSID rejected non-HTTPS cookie

Tags: php, apache, session, session-variables

I'm using Apache 2.4.41 with PHP 7.4.3.

I've this script that write a session

```
<?php
// uno.php

session_start();

$_SESSION['chiave'] = 'TEST';
echo session_save_path();
?>

<a href="due.php">Due</a>
```

When i click to Due link

```
<?php
// due.php

session_start();

print_r($_SESSION);
?>
```

I get that $_SESSION is empty.

Session.save_path is writeable and i see session file.

I see in firefox debug the messagge

```
Cookie PHPSESSID has been rejected because a non-HTTPS cookie can't be set as secure.
```

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

## Be secure

Use HTTPS instead of plain HTTP

## Be insecure and tell PHP you don't care.

Keep using HTTP and change the [`session.cookie_secure` option](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure) to `off` (which is its default value but one that must have been changed on your server).